# What Joomla events are triggered when a usergroup is changed?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, user-groups, plugin-events

I've been looking at [Joomla 3.x plugin events](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) to determine if a particular event gets triggered when a user's usergroup is changed. **Update**-specifically I've been trying to detect an event that is triggered whenever a user is added to or removed from a group. I've not found anything that specific, but it seems like onUserAfterSave will fire. I tried to test this using a custom plugin, but when I edited the usergroups using the usermanager in the backend, I was unable to see anything.

- Can anyone confirm that onUserAfterSave will fire on usergroup
  change?
- Does anyone know of any other events that would
  fire on usergroup change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want event for changing user's usergroup (on user edit view) or just event which is triggered on editing specific usergroup.

**Changing user will trigger (documented)**

- onUserBeforeSave
- onUserAfterSave

**Changing usergroup will trigger (undocumented, [see source code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_users/models/group.php#L26-L33))**

- onUserBeforeSaveGroup
- onUserAfterSaveGroup

Comment: onUserAfterSave seems to do what I want (I've gotten it to work now). I was a bit confused about the use of onUserAfterSaveGroup, but your answer at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/14829/115 clarified it for me. Thanks Rene :)