# Why doesn't onUserAfterSaveGroup get triggered when editing groups as Administrator?

Tags: joomla-3.x, user-groups, plugin-events

I'm having problems getting onUserAfterSaveGroup to fire on Joomla3.4.x

I've published a system plugin and tested that it works using `function onUserLogin()`, but when I try to use `function onUserAfterSaveGroup()` I fail to trigger the event.

To test the plugin, I logged into the frontend as the testuser and I logged into the backend as Admin and went to Users>Usermanager>testuser>Assigned User Groups. I then added testuser to a new usergroup and clicked Save.

In the plugin I had the following code (UPDATED)

```
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;
    jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
    class plgSystemcustomcheckJoomlaEvents extends JPlugin {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param   $subject
     * @param   array $config
     */     

    public function onUserAfterSaveGroup()
    {
        echo "onUserAfterSaveGroup triggered";
        die(); 
    }

    public function onUserLogin($user,$options)
    {
        /*THis WORkS */
        //echo 'onUserLogin triggered'; 
        //die();
    }
}
```

I expected to see the message "onUserAfterSaveGroup" show for testuser, but this didn't happen. I tried refreshing the page, but that didn't do anything either. The event wasn't triggered for Admin either (although I wasn't expecting it to).
Can someone explain why the event is not triggered for testuser?

This is a follow up to my question posted at [What Joomla events are triggered when a usergroup is changed?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14792/what-joomla-events-are-triggered-when-a-usergroup-is-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I wasn't clear enough on your previous question. `onUserAfterSaveGroup` get's triggered only if you change usergroup (not user). This is view `administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=groups`.

Comment: Thank Rene, I think I finally get it now- onUserAfterSaveGroup fires when creating a group. It doesn't fire when assigning a group to a user. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. You have to compare previous groups with new ones on event `onUserBeforeSave`, to see what was deleted / added. [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) should help.